# Ionic 2 build error on mac

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, ionic2, macos-sierra

When i run ionic cordova build anndroid. I get this error

```
Running command: /Users/mypc/documents/cordova/rohichurch/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/myoc/documents/cordova/rohichurch/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
Error: spawn EACCES
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx /folder
```

It is caused by permission problem. You could find more information on this problem here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-fix-this-error-spawn-eacces/20490

Answer (score 0):

You can either change the permissions by using :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/mypc/documents/cordova/rohichurch/platforms/android/gradlew
```

Or use sudo for your command :

sudo your_command